# Trying to validate PayPal payment amount - MySQL IPN

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to verify the mc_gross variable for a Pay Pal subscription IPN.

The following code keeps giving me "Resource id #12" value for the amount_data. The number I'm trying to verify is 0.05 that was put in the table when the user went to pay. The variable $id tests correctly and the number  (0.05) is there in the payment_amount column - so I don't know why it can't do this query. I am new to MYSQL so I apologize for any obvious mistakes.

```
$payment_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
   $amount_data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE payment_amount = '$payment_amount' AND id = '$id' "); 
    if ($amount_data != $_POST['mc_gross']) {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
        file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs/ipn.log',"\n###AMOUNT Don't MATCH Amount in Database='$payment_amount' Amount in requested='$amount_data'for id '$id'###\n",FILE_APPEND); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `mysql_fetch_row()`to get the $amount_data.Mysql_query() returns only the resouce id

```
$amount_data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE payment_amount = '$payment_amount' AND id = '$id' "); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($amount_data);

echo $row[0];
```

Check the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: But this returns an array. Can't I just SELECT the cell where payment_amount and id converge?

Comment: @user1390395  print_r($amount_data) and post your  result

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
$payment_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
    //$amount = mysql_query ("SELECT payment_amount FROM subscriber WHERE id = '$id'");
    $amount_data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE payment_amount = '$payment_amount' AND id = '$id' "); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($amount_data);
    if ($row[6] != $_POST['mc_gross']) {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
        file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs/ipn.log',"\n###AMOUNT Don't MATCH Amount in Database='$row[6]' Amount in requested='$payment_amount' for id '$id'###\n",FILE_APPEND); 
    }
```